# javascript event: hook when image starts loading ( already has naturalWidth & naturalHeight props but haven't loaded itself yet)

Tags: javascript, image, events, onload, userscripts

Is there such an event or trick to execute code when you can already get naturalsize of `<img>` after its creating with javascript but you don't have to wait when it's fully loaded (image might be 5mb so you'd have to wait 10+secs for it to be "loaded" but you can get its naturalsize right away (in few ms) when it just starts loading - I'd like to know that time when it gets naturalsize props and hook it)

Comment: seems like there is no native event for this . you can use `setInterval` with a small interval/delay

Comment: that's what I do now but setInterval doesn't work for Firefox+Noscript users, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Owyn - No event is going to work for noscript users (since no JS will run on any event) so your previous comment is baffling.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event `onloadedmetadata` that supposedly applies to `img` elements.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Copying from the source above:

> onloadedmetadata: Script to be run when meta data (like dimensions and duration) are loaded